# Generate json file with formatting

Tags: bash, shell

I have a curl command which generates json output. I want to add a few characters in generated file to be able to process it further.

Command:

```
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar "http://hostname/db/tbl_name/" >> db.json
```

This runs under a for loop which runs it for a db and tbl_name combination. Hence it ends up generating a number of json outputs(one for each table) concatenated together without any delimiter.

Output looks like :

{"columns":[{"name":"tbl_id","type":"varchar(50)"},{"name":"cret_timestmp","type":"timestamp"},{"name":"updt_timestmp","type":"timestamp"},{"name":"frst_nm","type":"varchar(50)"},{"name":"last_nm","type":"varchar(50)"},{"name":"acct_num","type":"varchar(15)"},{"name":"r_num","type":"varchar(15)"},{"name":"pid","type":"decimal(15,0)"},{"name":"ami_id","type":"varchar(30)"},{"name":"ssn","type":"varchar(9)"},{"name":"client_id","type":"varchar(30)"},{"name":"client_nm","type":"varchar(100)"},{"name":"info","type":"timestamp"},{"name":"rmx","type":"varchar(10)"},{"name":"id","type":"decimal(12,0)"},{"name":"ingest_timestamp","type":"string"},{"name":"incr_ingest_timestamp","type":"string"}],"database":"db_i","table":"db_tbl"}{"columns":[{"name":"key","type":"varchar(15)"},{"name":"foo_cd","type":"varchar(10)"},{"name":"foo_nm","type":"varchar(56)"},{"name":"tmc_regn_cd","type":"varchar(10)"},{"name":"tmc_mrkt_cd","type":"varchar(20)"},{"name":"mrkt_grp","type":"varchar(30)"},{"name":"ingest_timestamp","type":"string"},{"name":"incr_ingest_timestamp","type":"string"}],"database":"db_i","table":"ss_mv"}{"columns":[{"name":"bar_src_name","type":"string"},{"name":"bar_ent_name","type":"string"},{"name":"from_src","type":"string"},{"name":"reload","type":"string"},{"name":"column_mismatch","type":"string"},{"name":"xx_src_name","type":"string"},{"name":"xx_ent_name","type":"string"}],"database":"db_i","table":"test_table"}

Desired output is to start and end the output with []. Also I want to include "," between the end and beginning where column list starts.

So for ex: if the curl command runs against 3 tables as shown above, then the three generated jsons should be created like :

```
 [{json1},{json2},{json3}]
```

Number 1,2,3 ...etc corresponds to different tables in curl command running in for loop against a particular db whose json should be created in one file but with desired format.

instead of what I'm currently getting :

```
 {json1}{json2}{json3}
```

In the output pasted above, JSON 1 is :

{"columns":[{"name":"tbl_id","type":"varchar(50)"},{"name":"cret_timestmp","type":"timestamp"},{"name":"updt_timestmp","type":"timestamp"},{"name":"frst_nm","type":"varchar(50)"},{"name":"last_nm","type":"varchar(50)"},{"name":"acct_num","type":"varchar(15)"},{"name":"r_num","type":"varchar(15)"},{"name":"pid","type":"decimal(15,0)"},{"name":"ami_id","type":"varchar(30)"},{"name":"ssn","type":"varchar(9)"},{"name":"client_id","type":"varchar(30)"},{"name":"client_nm","type":"varchar(100)"},{"name":"info","type":"timestamp"},{"name":"rmx","type":"varchar(10)"},{"name":"id","type":"decimal(12,0)"},{"name":"ingest_timestamp","type":"string"}, 
{"name":"incr_ingest_timestamp","type":"string"}],"database":"db_i","table":"db_tbl"}

JSON 2 is :

{"columns":[{"name":"key","type":"varchar(15)"},{"name":"foo_cd","type":"varchar(10)"},{"name":"foo_nm","type":"varchar(56)"},{"name":"tmc_regn_cd","type":"varchar(10)"},{"name":"tmc_mrkt_cd","type":"varchar(20)"},{"name":"mrkt_grp","type":"varchar(30)"},{"name":"ingest_timestamp","type":"string"},{"name":"incr_ingest_timestamp","type":"string"}],"database":"db_i","table":"ss_mv"}

JSON 3 is :

{"columns":[{"name":"bar_src_name","type":"string"},{"name":"bar_ent_name","type":"string"},{"name":"from_src","type":"string"},{"name":"reload","type":"string"},{"name":"column_mismatch","type":"string"},{"name":"xx_src_name","type":"string"},{"name":"xx_ent_name","type":"string"}],"database":"db_i","table":"test_table"}

I hope the requirement is clear, thanks in advance, looking to achieve this via bash.

Comment: And what you say that you tried and is not working? Which are your programming doubts?

Comment: I was trying to use sed to add square brackets at the start and end and add a "," just two positions before everytime a column is encountered but couldn't make it work

Comment: For ex: I have tried below:

   ` for i in cat list;do`
      `curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar "http://hostname/db/tbl_name/" >> $list.json`
      `sed 's/$/,/' $list.json ## to add comma after each json`
     `done`

But if I use sed like this, the command creates a different file for each json line.

and then use awk at each generated file like:

    `awk '{print "["$0"]"}' db.json`

Comment: `sed 's/$/,/' $list.json` would append a comma to every EOL in a file. Is that what you want?

Comment: Does [JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh) help? That's probably as close as you'll come to "native" json support in bash, but you'll still fall short for pretty-printing existing JSON. Really, you want to use a language or tool that has native support for this format. `jq` would be perfect, but any of php, python, ruby, go or even perl would suffice.

Comment: If there's a newline between the documents (making it valid JSONL), that's delimiter enough.

Answer (score 3):

Use `jq -s`.

> `--slurp/-s`: Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array
>              and run the filter just once.

Here's an example:

```
$ cat file.json
{ "key": "value1" }
{ "key": "value2" }
{ "key":
"value3"}{"key": "value4"}

$ jq -s < file.json
[
  {
    "key": "value1"
  },
  {
    "key": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key": "value3"
  },
  {
    "key": "value4"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but unfortunately I can't install jq

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it correctly, but I think you are looking for something like

```
 echo "[$(cat *.json | paste -sd ',')]" > result.json
```

This works by creating a string that starts with `[` and ends with `]`, and in the middle, there are the contents of the json files concatenated (`cat`) and separated by commas (with the help of `paste`). That string is `echo`ed and written to a new file.

Comment: Great answer! Just one objection: you are building a potentially huge (memory hungry) `echo` command if there are many large JSON files.  `{ echo "["; cat *.json | paste -sd ','; echo "]"; } > result.json` does the same and is far more resource-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming input in valid JSONL format (one JSON document per line of input), you can embed a Python script inside your bash script:

```
slurpjson_py='
import json, sys
json.dump([json.loads(line.strip()) for line in sys.stdin], sys.stdout, indent=4)
sys.stdout.write("\n")
'

slurpjson() { python -c "$slurpjson_py" "$@"; }
```

If called as:

```
slurpjson <<EOF
{ "first": "document", "starting": "here" }
{ "second": "document", "ending": "here" }
EOF
```

...output is correctly:

```
[
    {
        "starting": "here",
        "first": "document"
    },
    {
        "second": "document",
        "ending": "here"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by running curl command and adding a "," with every line break using

```
sed 's/$/,/'
```

And then remove the last "," and added first and end [] using :

```
for i in *; do cat $i | sed '$ s/.$//' | awk '{print "["$0"]"}' > $json_dir/$i; done
```

Comment: `cat $i` is buggy -- try this with filenames with spaces, or a filename that starts with a dash -- and even when changed to `cat -- "$i"` to be safe with all possible names, it's still a needless performance cost to have an extra program (`cat` is a separate executable, not part of the shell) in your pipeline. Safer and faster to run `for in *; do sed '...' <"$i" | ... > "$json_dir/$i"`, with double quotes surrounding all expansions.